# JMS Exception : Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing

Tags: azure, jms, messaging, spring-jms

The JMS processing is succeeding for most of the requests and suddenly I noticed a failure for one of the requests. This is happening in production environment.

The background is `JmsOperations.class` - `convertAndSend` method posts the message to the Azure service bus - Topic.

The exception is:

```
Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:xxxx, SystemTracker:yyy, Timestamp:zzzz [condition = amqp:internal-error]
```

My initial assumption of the issue is due to some technical glitz in the service bus in Azure. But I'm not sure how to figure out the exact root cause.

Does any one have a better idea of this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution already?

Comment: Not yet. As this issue occurs rare , I haven't checked after that. Please do let me know if you find the solution for this.

Comment: Trying to upgrade now to latest version from 4.5.0 to 5.0.0

 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-servicebus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Unfortunately, it still occurs even after updating the dependency.